DynamoDB NodeJS V3 SDK Set type not
I am migrating from the V2 to the V3 SDK and I have some Set type data in DynamoDB that looks like this:
  "hitCount": {
    "NS": ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
  }

If I do a Get on it, the result looks like:
{
  wrapperName: "Set",
  values: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  type: "Number",
}

and when I move to the V3 SDK and run the Get I end up with hitCount being an Object of type Set.
I have looked into marshalling but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

I suppose, the V3 SDK is doing a better job of unmarshalling, and is probably the correct way to convert, but my code is running in an express server and Set fails to send, I just end up with an empty object, like hitCount: {}

What you share is low level DDB-JSON, where all attributes are stored as an object.
"hitCount": {
    "NS": ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
  }

Depending on what client you read with will give you different results. You can learn more about the JS clients here
